# How to write GC log to named pipe in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9

Before Java9, we can just specify -Xloggc:/my/named/pipe to log garbage collection messages into a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). However, when specifying `-Xlog:gc*:file=/my/named/pipe`, JVM 9 complains about the named pipe:

```
[0.003s][error][logging] Unable to log to file /my/named/pipe,  /my/named/pipe is not a regular file.
```

We are using Linux RedHat with jdk_9.0.1_x64.

How can we log GC messages to a named pipe in Java 9?

Comment: Which operating system is this, and which exact JVM? It's possible that this is just a regression.

Comment: Linux RedHat and jdk_9.0.1_x64

Comment: Please [edit] that information into the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the syntax specified under [Unified JVM Logging](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158), could you try replacing the arg from

```
-xlog:gc*.file=/my/named/pip
```

to

```
-Xlog:gc*=info:file=gctrace.txt
           ^  ^          ^
       level  colon   filename
```

or simply

```
-Xlog:gc*:file=gctrace.txt // since default level for gc logging is INFO
```